# jupyter notebook Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

just installed jupyter notebook, when I run jupyter notebook it says:

```
jupyter notebook Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

So was trying to check which commands exist it says:

```
jupyter --help 
... 
Available subcommands: kernel kernelspec migrate run troubleshoot trust
```

so no notebook command? so I tried:

```
jupyter run
```

it didn't fail, but not sure which port to access on localhost:8888 nothing there.. what do you think? anything i'm doing wrong?

UPDATE: more information about the commands I used and environment:

```
➜  ~ pip list | grep jupyter
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
jupyter-client (5.2.2)
jupyter-core (4.4.0)
➜  ~ history | grep pip
  826  python -m pip install ipykernel
  827  python -m pip install ipykernel\n
  828  sudo python -m pip install ipykernel\n
  943  python -m pip install ipykernel
 1530  python -m pip install ipykernel\n
 1543  python -m pip install ipykernel\n
 1548  pip install nympy
 1550  pip install --upgrade pip\n
 1551  pip install numpy\n
 1552  pip install pyspark
 1553  pip install plotly
 1555  pip install mypy
 1565  pip install pandas
 1570  pip install matplotlib
 1575  pip install hydrogen-scala
 1577  python -m pip install jupyter-scala
 1620  pip install nltk
 1621  pip install sklearn
 1622  pip install scipy
 1669  pip list | grep jupyter

➜  ~ jupyter troubleshoot
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
$PATH:
    /Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4rc1/bin
    /Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4rc1/bin
    /usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.0/libexec
    /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin
    /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/bin
    /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin
    /Users/myuser/.pyenv/shims
    /Users/myuser/.pyenv/bin
    /Users/myuser/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/bin
    /Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v8.4.0/bin
    /usr/local/bin
    /usr/bin
    /bin
    /usr/sbin
    /sbin
    /Users/myuser/.pyenv/bin
    /Users/myuser/.rvm/bin

sys.path:
    /Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4rc1/bin
    /Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4rc1/lib/python36.zip
    /Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4rc1/lib/python3.6
    /Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4rc1/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
    /Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4rc1/lib/python3.6/site-packages

sys.executable:
    /Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4rc1/bin/python

sys.version:
    3.6.4rc1 (default, Jan 25 2018, 23:18:04)
    [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)]

platform.platform():
    Darwin-17.3.0-x86_64-i386-64bit

which -a jupyter:
    /Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4rc1/bin/jupyter
    /Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4rc1/bin/jupyter
    /Users/myuser/.pyenv/shims/jupyter
    /usr/local/bin/jupyter

pip list:
    appnope (0.1.0)
    certifi (2018.1.18)
    chardet (3.0.4)
    cycler (0.10.0)
    decorator (4.2.1)
    idna (2.6)
    ipykernel (4.8.0)
    ipython (6.2.1)
    ipython-genutils (0.2.0)
    jedi (0.11.1)
    jsonschema (2.6.0)
    jupyter-client (5.2.2)
    jupyter-core (4.4.0)
    matplotlib (2.1.2)
    mypy (0.560)
    nbformat (4.4.0)
    nltk (3.2.5)
    numpy (1.14.0)
    pandas (0.22.0)
    parso (0.1.1)
    pexpect (4.3.1)
    pickleshare (0.7.4)
    pip (9.0.1)
    plotly (2.2.3)
    prompt-toolkit (1.0.15)
    psutil (5.4.3)
    ptyprocess (0.5.2)
    py4j (0.10.4)
    Pygments (2.2.0)
    pyparsing (2.2.0)
    pyspark (2.2.1)
    python-dateutil (2.6.1)
    pytz (2017.3)
    pyzmq (16.0.4)
    requests (2.18.4)
    scikit-learn (0.19.1)
    scipy (1.0.0)
    setuptools (28.8.0)
    simplegeneric (0.8.1)
    six (1.11.0)
    sklearn (0.0)
    tornado (4.5.3)
    traitlets (4.3.2)
    typed-ast (1.1.0)
    urllib3 (1.22)
    wcwidth (0.1.7)
```

Comment: what command did you use to install the notebook? can you run `pip list`, do you see a module called `jupyter-notebook`?

Comment: Hi updated question content with this information.

Comment: looks like anaconda is a powerful tool will give it a shot.

Comment: In your history I see a single ```jupyter-scala```, which is an addon for ```jupyter```, but does not contain it. See GitHub page of ```jupyter-scala```: https://github.com/jupyter-scala/jupyter-scala#jupyter-installation or the ```jupyter``` page: http://jupyter.org/install

Comment: (@LouiseDavies the module is just ```notebook``` I think)

Comment: just installed `anaconda` jupyter notebook starts up with `juypter notebook` on localhost:8888 with no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

installed anaconda from: https://anaconda.com and now `jupyter notebook` startsup with no problem.

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the issue with native python

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue in linux mint 19.

just type the following in your terminal

```
sudo apt install jupyter-notebook
```

then type`jupyter-notebook`
done.

Answer (score 4):

I faced similar issue. This is what I did to fix the issue (on Ubuntu 16.04) :

```
sudo apt-get remove ipython

sudo apt-get purge ipython

sudo apt-get autoremove

pip install jupyter
```

ipython seemed to be the problem, hence removing it fixed the issue.

I'm now able to run `jupyter notebook`